# Minecraft(ftb) lags with fps of 100/200

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am playing minecraft feed the beast with the Direwolf20 pack, and I got all settings maxed.
With this settings I get with an AMD R9 290 around 100/200 FPS.
But even with this much fps, it looks like 20/40 fps, although fraps says 100/200.
What could be the problem?
I got the latest version of java and drivers.

Comment: Are there many machines in your world? Does it also happen in a new world? What specific pack are you using?

Comment: I am using the ftb direwolf20 pack, and i just created a new world(empty)

Comment: Hmmm, if it was a world full of stuff I'd have an idea, but now I don't. Sorry.

Comment: may not be directly related but you may want to check your tps with /cofh tps

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for tech support related to modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for unmodded vanilla clients.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you feel like your fps is lower than your 'f3' debug screen shows is because your computer can't handle more than a set amount of fps. That is set by the amount of  [hertz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz), or hz you have.

Most computer run at 60hz, and that's what you probably have for your computer.

A few better computers run at 75hz, which is normally for special work engines (geek speech for a great computer). That's what I have on my computer.

And then there are the beastly gaming computers that cost a fortune... They can run about 144 fps on their games.

To check which of the three common types of computers you have, you can visit [this search page](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+check+your+computer%27s+hertz+windows+10) for more information. It will also help you change your monitor frequency if you can.

I hope I helped!